# Using a method in seeds.rb in Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, seed

I am trying to add a method to my *seeds.rb* so that I don't have to write a bunch of verbose code. However, depending on the placement of the `create_deliverable` method I get one of two error messages when running `db:setup`.

When method is before call

> rake aborted!
>   private method 'create_deliverable' called for #

When method is after call

> rake aborted!
>   undefined method `create_deliverable' for #

Is it not possible to uses methods in *seeds.rb*? Am I somehow calling the method incorrectly (I've tried calling with and without the `self.`)?

**Method**

```
def create_deliverable(complexity, project_phase_id, deliverable_type_id)
  Deliverable.create(:name => (0...8).map{65.+(rand(25)).chr}.join,
      :size => 2 + rand(6) + rand(6),
      :rate => 2 + rand(6) + rand(6),
      :deliverable_type_id => deliverable_type_id,
      :project_phase_id => project_phase_id,
      :complexity => complexity)
end
```

**Calling Code**

```
@wf_project.project_phases.each do |phase|
  DeliverableType.find_by_lifecycle_phase(phase.lifecycle_phase_id).each do
    |type|
    self.create_deliverable("Low", type.id, phase.id)

    self.create_deliverable("Medium", type.id, phase.id)

    self.create_deliverable("High", type.id, phase.id)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks to me like you placed your `create_deliverable` method after `private` access modifier in your script. Put it after `public`.

```
public

    def create_deliverable(complexity, project_phase_id, deliverable_type_id)
      Deliverable.create(:name => (0...8).map{65.+(rand(25)).chr}.join,
          :size => 2 + rand(6) + rand(6),
          :rate => 2 + rand(6) + rand(6),
          :deliverable_type_id => deliverable_type_id,
          :project_phase_id => project_phase_id,
          :complexity => complexity)
    end
private # to keep the rest of methods private
```

Comment: seeds.rb doesn't define any classes, so public and private doesn't matter. What matters is that you define the method before executing it.

Answer (score 21):

Make sure you define the method before calling it:

```
def test_method
  puts "Hello!"
end

test_method
```

Comment: This is actually a better answer, because seeds.rb doesn't define a class, so public/private methods don't matter.

Answer (score 15):

If you're going to use `self.`, use it on the method definition, not the call.

```
def self.create_deliverable(...)
    ...
end
...
create_deliverable("Low", type.id, phase.id)
...
```

It's my understanding that `.rb` files without a class definition get wrapped in an anonymous ruby class when they are run, so defining the method on self should work just fine.

Comment: +1 for the explanation about how `.rb` files without a class definition get wrapped in an anonymous ruby class